# validate array json contains several unordered objects using json schema

Tags: jsonschema

### Problem

I want to use json schema draft 7 to validate that an array contains several unordered objects. For example, the array should contains student A, B, regardless of their orders.

```
[{"name": "A"}, {"name": "B"}] //valid
[{"name": "B"}, {"name": "A"}] //valid
[{"name": "A"}, {"name": "C"}, {"name": "B"}] //extra students also valid
[] or [{"name": "A"}] or [{"name": "B"}] //invalid
```

### Current Attempt

json schema `contains` keyword doesn't support a list

json schema `Tuple validation` keyword must be ordered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `allOf` applicator keyword. You need to define multiple `contains` clauses.

`allOf` allows you to define multiple schemas which must all pass.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "contains": {
        "required": ["name"],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "const": "A"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "contains": {
        "required": ["name"],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "const": "B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Live demo here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVIQA2ugPISSiANpbkiOEkvaQmNhUIBLeGBPXbt1P1wBHAFdnXxETcxB4QnxcVABdTRsvMmp+FmpcfgpnXHcoKwsku0jojwLCuwc3ChNUAEFUMqSAX0bLFsS2sqaE208vVEqnV1zSPqSffyCQsNRimJB41rsUtIysnNKO8Yio+dGl-vs2MGq81AAhBq2vdvLbm66LWIQmkHUQZygQcxsxsjmaiB6iALN0LH9ZrtAQBhK7IMG-MqQkpnECXEE2dqxEBNIA).

Comment: You should put a `required` and a `type` in each of those, too.

Comment: `required` is necessary, but `type` is not required because `const` doesn't care about type. BUT, adding `type` couldn't hurt, and it shows intent.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect suggested changes.